# How do I find the general equation for $\frac{dP}{dt} = (aP - bP^2) + C$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find the general solution to this differential equation?
$$
\frac{dP}{dt} = (aP - bP^2) + C
$$

I can get the solution as

$$P=\frac{ae^{at+C}}{1+be^{at+C}}$$

when $C=0$ but I am not sure how to solve it when $C$ is any real constant, for example $C=10$.

Comment: Is $c$ different from the constant of integration $C$?

Comment: Sneaking at laplace tables on wikipedia I get something like
$
sL(P)(s)-P(0) = \left(aL(P)(s)-b(2\pi i)^{-1}\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{\Re(\sigma)-iT}^{\Re(\sigma)+iT}[L(P)(\sigma)L(P)(s-\sigma)d\sigma]\right) + Cs^{-1}
$
which doesn't look nice at all :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{dP}{dt} = aP - bP^2 + C\quad$ is a separable ODE.

$dt=\frac{dP}{aP - bP^2 + C}\quad\to\quad t=\int\frac{dP}{aP - bP^2 + C}+$constant.

The integration leads to $t$ as a fonction of $P$. The inverse function is $P(t)$. This is a tedious calculs, but possible anyways.

Another way consists to apply the method for solving the Riccati ODEs :

Change of function : $\quad P(t)=\frac{1}{b\:y(t)}\frac{dy}{dt}\quad$ where $y(t)$ is the function to be found.

The ODE is transformed to :
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-a\frac{dy}{dt}-Cby=0$$
This is a second order linear ODE with constant coefficients, easy to solve.

So, you obtain the function $y(t)$ and then $P(t)=\frac{1}{b\:y}\frac{dy}{dt}$

Note : They are two arbitrary constant in $y(t)$. Only one arbitrary constant remains after the calculus of $\frac{1}{b\:y}\frac{dy}{dt}$